# Custom Log4j appender sharing with Tomcat 7?

Tags: tomcat, grails, log4j

I would like to share a [TimeAndSizeRollingAppender](http://www.simonsite.org.uk/) log4j appender between several Grails applications deployed to a single Tomcat instance.

I'm receiving an error when I deploy the custom appender jar to **$CATALINA_BASE/lib** or **$CATALINA_HOME/lib**:

```
script137576019951183098840.groovy: 39: unable to resolve class uk.org.simonsite.log4j.appender.TimeAndSizeRollingAppender @ line 39, column 18.                                                                                                    
       appender new uk.org.simonsite.log4j.appender.TimeAndSizeRollingAppender(
                ^
1 error

Aug 5, 2013 8:36:40 PM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.cfg.ConfigurationHelper warn
```

It works if I deploy the jar to **$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/app1/WEB-INF/lib** and **$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/app2/WEB-INF/lib**.  However I would like to keep this deployment detail external from the application itself.

I'm using the following [externalized configuration](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configExternalized) to configure logging in the applications:

**app1-config.groovy**

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        appender new uk.org.simonsite.log4j.appender.TimeAndSizeRollingAppender(
            name: "file",
            file: "app1.log",
            threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.ALL,
            datePattern: ".yyyy-MM-dd",
            compressionAlgorithm: "ZIP",
            compressionMinQueueSize: 2,
            layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%d{MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c %M %x%n%p: %m%n"))
    }
}
```

**app2-config.groovy**

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        appender new uk.org.simonsite.log4j.appender.TimeAndSizeRollingAppender(
            name: "file",
            file: "app2.log",
            threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.ALL,
            datePattern: ".yyyy-MM-dd",
            compressionAlgorithm: "ZIP",
            compressionMinQueueSize: 2,
            layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%d{MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c %M %x%n%p: %m%n"))
    }
}
```

How can I share a common appender outside of the application lib with Tomcat?

Comment: Do you have `common.loader` in `catalina.properties` set to look at `${catalina.base}/lib`? Jars added to tomcat lib directory is looked at in the end during classloading. To make sure that the last resort works, the `common.loader` should have an indication to look at Tomcat's `lib` directory for any class that needs to be added to classpath. By default it is specified.

Comment: @dmahapatro Yes, the common.loader property includes `${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar`.

Comment: You get an error while deploying the custom appender jar to the lib? Which jar were you deploying/placing?

Comment: For a sanity check, can we also see that the same jar is not in the application classpath anywhere due to which it may clash and fail to load. A `dependency-report` will make it clear.

Comment: @dmahapatro The jar file is log4j-rolling-appender-20130711-2159.jar.  The jar/class does not exist and is not referenced in the application or classpath except as noted above.  It seems like Grails is not picking up the Tomcat common.loader classpath.